# regex print all lines before next new line with sed

Tags: regex, awk, sed, text-processing

I have the following file contents:

```
# example, Group, example.com
 dn: cn=example,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com
 cn: example
 gidNumber: 2344
 objectClass: posixGroup
 objectClass: top
 memberUid: michael.george
 memberUid: dan.bworn
 memberUid: msmith
 memberUid: d.bob

# example-dev, Group, example.com
 dn: cn=example-dev,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com
 cn: example-dev
 gidNumber: 2345
 objectClass: posixGroup
 objectClass: top
 memberUid: alexandra.shedy
 memberUid: alex.mansi
 memberUid: bclara
 memberUid: hwan.nex
```

I want to print the first block upon the next new line, so it should be:

```
# example, Group, example.com
 dn: cn=example,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com
 cn: example
 gidNumber: 2344
 objectClass: posixGroup
 objectClass: top
 memberUid: michael.george
 memberUid: dan.bworn
 memberUid: msmith
 memberUid: d.bob
```

I've tried the `cat for_stack.txt | sed  -n '/# example/,/^$/p'` but it gets first and the second block as well because `# example` and `# example-dev` strings are similar.

Tried using the regex `^$` symbols: `cat for_stack.txt | sed  -n '/^# example$/,/^$/p'` but it doesn't return anything. Seems like using regex tricks wont works. Any idea?

Comment: `sed  -n '/^# example,/,/^$/p'`? Or, `sed  -En '/^# example(,|$)/,/^$/p'`

Comment: Not clear why this got downvotes. This O.P. has a good Q here, with sample input, expected output and .... gasp, some code! What's not to like? Good luck catalin!

Comment: I voted to close because of [the OPs comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60670816/regex-print-all-lines-before-next-new-line-with-sed#comment107341359_60670923) that makes this question extremely incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following (written and tested with shown samples only).

```
awk '/^# example/{count1++} /dn:/{count++};count<=1 && NF && count1<2' Input_file
```

Comment: not reliable, using awk '/^# example-dev/{count1++} /dn:/{count++};count<=1 && NF && count1<2' for_stack.txt for the second block shows me the results from first block.

Comment: @catalin, I believe you want to print 1st block only correct?

Comment: Well, yes, I need to print the first block using a search pattern, and when searching for a different pattern, it display the wrong block.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex here. Run awk in paragraph mode and print the first record

```
awk NR==1 RS= file
```

If `file` is too large, the following will be way more performative

```
awk 'NR==1{print;exit}' RS= file
```

Comment: Seems it gets the first block. How can I get it, delete it, then take again the next one which will be now the first? File has a lot of blocks and I need to process them all

Comment: @catalin Your question does not mention *getting, deleting and then taking again the next one*. Tbh if it did I wouldn't post an answer because that's too broad

Comment: Sorry, I will edit it

Comment: Ah, readers don't like expanding Qs ;-) ... But still. Anyway, if you're attempting to ultimately process the whole file, then I think you want to approach this differently, and write code that reads the file one time, and has conditional logic that deals with the different `case`s that you need to process. Good luck @catalin !